# Less in terminal with fonts (Markdown viewing)?

Tags: command-line, markdown, font, text

I have just started looking into options for reading Markdown files in the terminal, and I've consulted these resources:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/markdown-viewer
- https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/3xgd2w/good_markdown_viewer_in_terminal/

I got more interested when I read about `mdless` here https://brettterpstra.com/2015/08/21/mdless-better-markdown-in-terminal/ - and I saw an example of an image being rendered in the terminal:

[image: mdless]

So, if rendering of images is possible in terminal, probably font rendering is too - so I was thinking about the following:

- Is there a Markdown terminal viewer, that could render normal text in different font from code text font *in the terminal*?

I would be merely interested in a different monospaced font for "normal text", so the font engine would not really need to support kerning and all other font intricacies (and would also like, if the this reader could change the terminal color scheme from the usual white text on black background, to black text on white background).

Or if there is nothing specific like that, I could generalize my request as:

- Is there a terminal reader like `less`, which would allow for changing font (and background and text color) *in the terminal* at runtime? (say by using a switch like in the pseudocode: `turboless -tc black -bc while -font "Courier" file.txt`)

A tricky thing for me, is that I usually use MSYS2 `bash` in Windows Terminal on Windows 10, and I'm not sure if this technology stack can render images in terminal - but there is for instance `wezterm` terminal, which does build on Windows, and:

https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/imgcat.html

> wezterm implements support for the iTerm2 inline images protocol and provides a handy `imgcat` subcommand to make it easy to try out. Because the protocol is just a protocol, wezterm's `imgcat` also renders images in iTerm2.

... and this seems it works on Windows builds too:

[image: wezterm-imgcat]

... so in theory, what I'm looking for should be possible - though I'm not sure if anything like that exists already ...